# check if the editText is empty. if else Android

Tags: android, eclipse, if-statement, android-edittext, is-empty

This is my onClick method. i try to get the value from edittext and do calculation.
i use "if" to check either the edittext is empty or not. the "if" can check the edittext is empty no problem.
the problem is after checked it is empty, the key in value, the app is crashed. please help me on this, im a android beginner.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Editable editableValue_x1 = et_x1.getText(),
                editableValue_x2 = et_x2.getText(),
                editableValue_x3 = et_x3.getText(),
                editableValue_x4 = et_x4.getText(),
                editableValue_x5 = et_x5.getText(),
                editableValue_x6 = et_x6.getText(),
                editableValue_x7 = et_x7.getText(),
                editableValue_x8 = et_x8.getText(),
                editableValue_x9 = et_x9.getText(),                             
                editableValue_x10 = et_x10.getText();

       Editable editableValue_y1 = et_y1.getText(),
                editableValue_y2 = et_y2.getText(),
                editableValue_y3 = et_y3.getText(),
                editableValue_y4 = et_y4.getText(),
                editableValue_y5 = et_y5.getText(),
                editableValue_y6 = et_y6.getText(),
                editableValue_y7 = et_y7.getText(),
                editableValue_y8 = et_y8.getText(),
                editableValue_y9 = et_y9.getText(),                             
                editableValue_y10 = et_y10.getText();

       String x1 = et_x1.getText().toString();
       String x2 = et_x2.getText().toString();
       String x3 = et_x3.getText().toString();
       String x4 = et_x4.getText().toString();
       String x5 = et_x5.getText().toString();
       String x6 = et_x6.getText().toString();
       String x7 = et_x7.getText().toString();
       String x8 = et_x8.getText().toString();
       String x9 = et_x9.getText().toString();
       String x10 = et_x10.getText().toString();
```

//this is my "if" statement

```
 String [] x = {x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10};
       for (int i = 1 ; i<11 ; i++)
       if(TextUtils.isEmpty(x[i])) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incomplete values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
       }


float value_x1 = 0,
          value_x2 = 0,
          value_x3 = 0,
          value_x4 = 0,
          value_x5 = 0,
          value_x6 = 0,
          value_x7 = 0,
          value_x8 = 0,
          value_x9 = 0,
          value_x10 = 0,         
          value_y1 = 0,
          value_y2 = 0,
          value_y3 = 0,
          value_y4 = 0,
          value_y5 = 0,
          value_y6 = 0,
          value_y7 = 0,
          value_y8 = 0,
          value_y9 = 0,
          value_y10 = 0,          
          result_sum_x,
          result_sum_y,
          result_sum_x2,
          result_sum_y2,
          result_sum_xy,
          result_sxx,
          result_sxy,
          result_beta1,
          result_beta0;

   if (editableValue_x1 != null)
        value_x1 = Float.parseFloat(editableValue_x1.toString());


   if (editableValue_x2 != null)
        value_x2 = Float.parseFloat(editableValue_x2.toString());


   if (editableValue_x3 != null)
        value_x3 = Float.parseFloat(editableValue_x3.toString());


   if (editableValue_x4 != null)
        value_x4 = Float.parseFloat(editableValue_x4.toString());


   if (editableValue_x5 != null)
        value_x5 = Float.parseFloat(editableValue_x5.toString());


   if (editableValue_x6 != null)
        value_x6 = Float.parseFloat(editableValue_x6.toString());


   if (editableValue_x7 != null)
        value_x7 = Float.parseFloat(editableValue_x7.toString());


   if (editableValue_x8 != null)
        value_x8 = Float.parseFloat(editableValue_x8.toString());


   if (editableValue_x9 != null)
        value_x9 = Float.parseFloat(editableValue_x9.toString());


   if (editableValue_x10 != null)
        value_x10 = Float.parseFloat(editableValue_x10.toString());


   if (editableValue_y1 != null)
        value_y1 = Float.parseFloat(editableValue_y1.toString());


   if (editableValue_y2 != null)
        value_y2 = Float.parseFloat(editableValue_y2.toString());


   if (editableValue_y3 != null)
        value_y3 = Float.parseFloat(editableValue_y3.toString());


   if (editableValue_y4 != null)
        value_y4 = Float.parseFloat(editableValue_y4.toString());


   if (editableValue_y5 != null)
        value_y5 = Float.parseFloat(editableValue_y5.toString());


   if (editableValue_y6 != null)
        value_y6 = Float.parseFloat(editableValue_y6.toString());


   if (editableValue_y7 != null)
        value_y7 = Float.parseFloat(editableValue_y7.toString());


   if (editableValue_y8 != null)
        value_y8 = Float.parseFloat(editableValue_y8.toString());


   if (editableValue_y9 != null)
        value_y9 = Float.parseFloat(editableValue_y9.toString());


   if (editableValue_y10 != null)
        value_y10 = Float.parseFloat(editableValue_y10.toString());





  result_sum_x = value_x1 + value_x2 + value_x3 + value_x4 + value_x5 + value_x6 + value_x7 + value_x8 + value_x9 + value_x10;

  result_sum_y = value_y1 + value_y2 + value_y3 + value_y4 + value_y5 + value_y6 + value_y7 + value_y8 + value_y9 + value_y10;

  result_sum_x2 = (value_x1 * value_x1) + (value_x2 * value_x2) + (value_x3 * value_x3) + (value_x4 * value_x4) + 
          (value_x5 * value_x5) + (value_x6 * value_x6) + (value_x7 * value_x7) + (value_x8 * value_x8) + 
          (value_x9 * value_x9) + (value_x10 * value_x10);

  result_sum_y2 = (value_y1 * value_y1) + (value_y2 * value_y2) + (value_y3 * value_y3) + (value_y4 * value_y4) + 
          (value_y5 * value_y5) + (value_y6 * value_y6) + (value_y7 * value_y7) + (value_y8 * value_y8) + 
          (value_y9 * value_y9) + (value_y10 * value_y10);

  result_sum_xy = (value_x1 * value_y1) + (value_x2 * value_y2) + (value_x3 * value_y3) + (value_x4 * value_y4) + 
          (value_x5 * value_y5) + (value_x6 * value_y6) + (value_x7 * value_y7) + (value_x8 * value_y8) + 
          (value_x9 * value_y9) + (value_x10 * value_y10);

  result_sxx = result_sum_x2 - ((result_sum_x * result_sum_x)/10);

  result_sxy = result_sum_xy - ((result_sum_x * result_sum_y)/10);

  result_beta1 = result_sxy / result_sxx;

  result_beta0 = ((result_sum_y)/10) - (result_beta1 * (result_sum_x / 10));



  ResultSumX.setText(""+ result_sum_x );
  ResultSumY.setText(""+ result_sum_y );
  ResultSumX2.setText(""+ result_sum_x2 );
  ResultSumY2.setText(""+ result_sum_y2 );
  ResultSumXY.setText(""+ result_sum_xy );
  ResultSXX.setText(""+ result_sxx);
  ResultSXY.setText(""+ result_sxy);
  ResultBeta1.setText(""+ result_beta1);
  ResultBeta0.setText(""+ result_beta0);
  ResultModel.setText("y = "+ result_beta0 + "+" + result_beta1 +"x");



}});
```

Comment: could you please post your error stack trace and the line on which you get the error precisely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the if statements in the following way

```
if (x1 != null)
```

instead of

```
if (editableValue_x1 != null)
```

And also change the for loop part,

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++)
   if(TextUtils.isEmpty(x[i])) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incomplete values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
 }
```

Comment: @abyss Check the update, You have a problem in the for loop part also.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
for (int i = 1 ; i<11 ; i++)
```

with:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, instead of all those variables and lengthy code, create one `Editable` array, initialize it to `editablevalue_x1`...`editablevalue_y10` and perform everything else in loops:

```
Editable[] editables = {editablevalue_x1, editablevalue_x2, ..., 
                        editablevalue_y1, ..., editabledvalue_y10};

List<Float> values = new ArrayList<Float>();
for(Editable editable: editables) {
    string s = editable.getText().toString();
    if(s!=null)
        values.add(Float.parse(s));
    else
        values.add(null);
}

// Do whatever you want with values, this times with loops for adding and multiplying
```

This will make finding the bug *a whole lot easier* (chances are it'll eliminate the bug altogether)

Comment: so the x and y do in this Editable[]?

Comment: Yes, put all of them in the array. If there's a real reason to distinguish between the two, use two arrays, one for Xs and one for Ys.

Comment: and i should remove my if statement and put in your code?

Comment: sry im a beginner. im not really understand the code. can u explain it to me?